# SQL Server 2014 Features Required for SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sql-server

I'm migrating a simple SharePoint installation (WSS 3.0 with internal DB) to SharePoint Foundation 2013 backed by SQL Server 2014. SQL Server 2014 seems to have a lot of options about which features I can run. I only want to run the minimum that would actually get used. Which features do I need to install?

I saw someone asked a similar question here: [Recommended SQL Server 2008 R2 instance features for Sharepoint Foundation 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40676/recommended-sql-server-2008-r2-instance-features-for-sharepoint-foundation-2010), I'm asking the same question but with different instances of the products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only minimum that you actually need is exactly the answer in the old post. The top one called "Database Engine Service" for the actual SQL engine and "Management tools - basic/complete" for Management Studio.

This is what most people choose to go with when setting up a development or a minimal foundation server, as the rest is just additional features for example Reporting Services or PowerPivot that is not even included in SharePoint foundation.